# Circles and click events in Raphaël graphic library

Tags: javascript, graphics

I'm trying to use Raphaël JS library. I just want to have some circles and change their color when user clicks on them. But I cannot understand why my code doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

Code here http://jsfiddle.net/Xj4GA/ and below.

```
 window.onload = function () {

                var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 640, 480);

                circles = paper.set();

                circles.push(paper.circle(20, 20, 10));  
                circles.push(paper.circle(30, 30, 10));
                circles.push(paper.circle(50, 60, 10));
                circles.push(paper.circle(120, 420, 10));
                circles.push(paper.circle(520, 20, 10));
                circles.push(paper.circle(230, 280, 10));
                circles.push(paper.circle(320, 260, 10));

                for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                    circles[i].click(function () {
                        alert('balblaba');
                        //this.attr("stroke", "Red");
                    });
                }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fill it `circles.attr({fill: "red"});`

Comment: Well...Handler of onclick event doesnt work whatever i to do fill circle or set color of stroke. In my example when i click on a circle the page must show me box "balblaba" but i see nothing.

Comment: The OP explained that he intends to fill the circles on a click event, not on any other situation.

Comment: oppsss... then let the clicks on the border circle... it's vector format.

Comment: @aavezel Thanks. Why documentation doesnt contain that point?

Comment: You can also catch the click on the papper and calculate a circle.

Comment: @Neir0 I can not say.  I am not the author